# iOS Code Displays White Field Rather Than Image Series

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The code below is supposed to display a series of images in an infinite, connected loop. Instead, it just displays a totally white field. Thanks to Aaron Hayman for getting me this far.

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    //Arrangement
    NSArray *imageViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];
    CGRect cRect = scrollView1.bounds;
    UIImageView *cView; 
    for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.count; i++)
    {
        cView = [imageViews objectAtIndex:i];
        cView.frame = cRect;
        [scrollView1 addSubview:cView];
        cRect.origin.x += cRect.size.width;
    }
    scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cRect.origin.x, scrollView1.bounds.size.height);
    scrollView1.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView1.bounds.size.width, 0); //should be the center page in a 3 page setup

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    scrollView1.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);
}
```

FOLLOW UP:

Nothing I'm doing is making any difference. Currently, my code looks like this, but I'm changing everything I can think of to no avail.

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    //Horizontal arrangement
    NSObject *image1 = @"image1.png";
    NSObject *image2 = @"image2.png";
    NSObject *image3 = @"image3.png";
    NSArray *imageViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, nil];
    CGRect cRect = scrollView1.bounds;
    UIImageView *cView; 
    for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.count; i++)
    {
        cView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageViews objectAtIndex:i]]];
        cView.frame = cRect;
        [scrollView1 addSubview:cView];
        cRect.origin.x += cRect.size.width;
    }
    scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cRect.origin.x, scrollView1.bounds.size.height);
    scrollView1.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView1.bounds.size.width, 0); //should be the center page in a 3 page setup

    [self layoutScrollImages];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    scrollView1.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initiate a UIImageView. You want to do something like this:

```
        NSArray *imageViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];
        CGRect cRect;
        UIImageView *cView; 
        for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.count; i++)
        {
            cView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageName:[imageViews objectAtIndex:i]]];
            cRect = cView.frame;
            cRect.origin.x += scrollView1.frame.size.width;
            cView.frame = cRect;
            [scrollView1 addSubview:cView];
            NSLog(@"imageView bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cView.frame));
        }
```

Edit: 
Try the above and see if anything shows up. Here are some thoughts:

1. Are you sure that you aren't setting the imageView to have 0 height/width? I threw in an NSLog statement to the loop. It will print the frame of the imageView.
2. Have you tried adding the images to self.view instead of scrollView1? That would be a good way to make sure that the problem doesn't have to do with the frame of scrollView1. Or use the following:
   NSLog(@"imageView bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(scrollView1.frame));

Comment: Added a 'd' to imageName and still had no real change. Could it have something to do with the way I'm writing the array?